# Is "I lost my bus" correct usage?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say, "I lost my bus," when you miss a bus? I have seen it commonly used.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Certainly not in American English. I've never seen it when reading British books, either; in fact, I don't recall seeing or hearing it in my life.

If I were to hear it, I'd assume *lost* meant "misplaced" and were meant as a joke.

On the other hand, the questioner's profile says he's Indian, and I don't know Indian English at all. Perhaps this is common there, though [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22lost+his|my+bus%22+site%3A.in) seems to imply otherwise.

**Edit:** Others' comments on this answer indicate that this is considered incorrect in both the U.K. and India.

Comment: Just to confirm, we wouldn't say it in the UK either.

Comment: As an Indian I would like to confirm that this is by no means appropriate Indian english.

Answer (score 9):

It's probably a recent phenomenon and I believe a literal translation of the Spanish

> He perdido [el avión, el bus...].

Comment: Same thing in Portuguese

Comment: Same thing in French

Comment: Never heard it in French ("j'ai perdu mon bus" ??)

Comment: Right, French would be “j’ai raté mon bus”, not “perdu”. (raté = missed, failed)

Comment: In Italian, there is just a verb for _miss_ and _lost_: _perdere_.

Answer (score 7):

It is more appropriate to use *missed my bus*. I've never heard people say “I lost my bus” to imply the meaning you are referring to. I think it can be used in situations when a bus once owned is destroyed, but that is rare.

I fancy that this sentence is from a story where the speaker runs some transport agency and the bus service he/she had run earlier is terminated or is out of his/her control. :)

Comment: It would make sense if a bus service was stopped, "I lost my bus to work, I now have to drive everyday" but that's the only context I can think of in BE.

Comment: Other possibilities- following a bus in a car- "Don't lose the bus". "Don't lose the bus- make sure the deposit is remitted before Friday or the team will be walking".

Answer (score 6):

You can lose something if you once possessed it. You can lose your mind, your marbles, and your keys, but most ordinary people will never lose their bus or their plane.

Comment: I'd rather say something you once possessed or could have had. example: you've just lost the game.[the victory]

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've listened the expression to lose the bus in America, I was talking to my friend and he said to me: tomorrow, don't lose the bus, don't miss school. It was interesting that he used both verbs. PS: He is American, born and raised in Kansas. Maybe it is some Portuguese or Spanish influence on his speech, even tho there are few immigrants here. Maybe it's starting to be interchangeable just like miss/lose an opportunity.

Comment: Highly doubtful in terms of interchangeability.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in American English you can lose the bus only when there is only one bus  to take, i.e. the school bus which comes by only once and that is the only context in which I would use it. That is why you never 'lose a train' because many trains run daily.

Comment: Hello, Anne. Please add supporting references; unsupported answers often come across as (and sometimes are) mere opinion, or non-standard usages encountered so rarely as to be inadmissible on ELU.

Answer (score 0):

I have  never  heard  in India people say  that **I  lost  my  bus.**

They  say

> **I  lost  my  purse if  they  lose  it.  I  left  it  at home   or  I  forgot  it   at  home**

They  say

> **I  have  missed  the  bus  or I  missed  the  bus.**